# Spark running on YARN - What does a real life example's workflow look like?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have been reading up on Hadoop, YARN and SPARK. What makes sense to me thus far is what I have summarized below.

> Hadoop MapReduce: Client choses an input file and hands if off to
>   Hadoop (or YARN). Hadoop takes care of splitting the flie based on
>   user's InputFormat and stores it on as many nodes that are available
>   and configured Client submits a job (map-reduce) to YARN, which
>   copeies the jar to available Data Nodes and executes the job. YARN is
>   the orchestrator that takes care of all the scheduling and running of
>   the actual tasks
>
> Spark: Given a job, input and a bunch of configuration parameters, it
>   can run your job, which could be a series of transformations and
>   provide you the output.
>
> I also understand MapReduce is a batch based processing paradigm and
>   SPARK is more suited for micro batch or stream based data.

There are a lot of articles that talks about how Spark can run on YARN and how they are complimentary, but none have managed to help me understand how those two come together during an acutal workflow. For example when a client has a job to submit, read a huge file and do a bunch of transformations what does the workflow look like when using Spark on YARN. Let us assume that the client's input file is a 100GB text file. Please include as much details as possible

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the large file is stored in HDFS. In HDFS the file is divided into blocks of some size (default 128 MB).

That means your **100GB file** will be divided into **800 blocks**. Each block will be replicated and can be stored on different node in the cluster.

When reading the file with Hadoop `InputFormat` list of splits with location is obtained first. Then there is created one task per each splits. That you will get 800 parallel tasks that are executed by runtime.

Basically the input process is the same for *MapReduce* and *Spark*, because both of the use *Hadoop Input Formats*.

Both of them will process each `InputSplit` in separate task. The main difference is that Spark has more rich set of transformations and can optimize the workflow if there is a chain of transformations that can be applied at once. As opposed to *MapReduce* where is always *map* and *reduce* phase only.

---

**YARN** stands for "Yet another resource negotiator". When a new job with some resource requirement (memory, processors) is submitted it is the responsibility of YARN to check if the needed resources are available on the cluster. If other jobs are running on the cluster are taking up too much of the resources then the new job will be made to wait till the prevoius jobs complete and resources are available.

YARN will allocate enough *containers* in the cluster for the workers and also one for the Spark driver. In each of these containers JVM is started with given resources. Each Spark worker can process multiple tasks in parallel (depends on the configured *number of cores* per executor).

e.g.

*If you set 8 cores per Spark executor, YARN tries to allocated 101 containers in the cluster tu run 100 Spark workers + 1 Spark master (driver). Each of the workers will process 8 tasks in parallel (because of 8 cores).*